# "Cry" versus "weep"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

When to use *cry* and when to use *weep*? Which one goes more formal? Which one should have preference in general use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, *weep* is more about tears, while *cry* is more about the sound.

---

Merriam-Webster entries:

[Weep](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weep): [*vi* 1] to express passion (as grief) by shedding tears

[Cry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cry): [*vi* 2] to shed tears often **noisily**

[Sob](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sob): [*vi* 1b] to cry or weep with convulsive catching of the breath

Comment: Some times we use "He's crying." and sometimes "He's weeping."(in the same context also). Why ?

Comment: @Akshay Thakur What do you mean by _the same context_. Just the same situation or the same page? Despite that, I guess we just use different words for a similar meaning to make articles look good.

Comment: I meant that Meaning of both sentences are same , then when to use "cry" and when "weep" ?

Comment: @Akshay Thakur, It depends. _weep_ is more literary and more dramatic.

Answer (score 5):

*Weep* is a little more archaic or poetic, so there's a mild preference for using *cry* instead.  The only time you must use *weep* rather than *cry* is if you think the wrong meaning of *cry* will be understood by mistake.

Comment: I think *Weep* is a **lot** more archaic / poetic, and rarely occurs in everyday speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: _weep_ is rare, true, but _cry_ is pretty uncommon in everyday speech too, so I don't think the distinction is as dramatic as you're making out.

Comment: I don't think *cry* is uncommon at all. Babies cry all the time, but they don't often weep. In my experience, weeping is something only running sores and people in mental distress do. Crying is much more generic, covering lacrimation due to physical pain, talking loudly, animal noises, etc.